# How to change color of turtlesim background using python code

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, guys, I'm trying to publish data to turtlesim color_sensor that is trying to display different colors my problem is it publishing data but it's not working. I did call **$ rosservice call /clea**r after running program but it didn't work

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

    import rospy
    from turtlesim.msg import Color
      
    rospy.init_node('color_sensor')
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/turtle1/color_sensor',Color,queue_size=4)
    rate = rospy.Rate(50)
    change=Color()
    change.r=255
    change.g=255
    change.b=255
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
       pub.publish(change)
       print  change
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283346/how-to-change-color-of-turtlesim-background-using-python-code/) by [bharadwaj26](https://answers.ros.org/users/33000/bharadwaj26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-02-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-21**:\

> but it didn't work

what does this mean?

**Comment by [bharadwaj26](https://answers.ros.org/users/33000/bharadwaj26/) on 2018-02-21**:
it's not publishing those RGB values to color_sensor, even though I am publishing it.i,e Background color is not changing to White(255,255,255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for changing turtlesim Background color you must set  param not publish via topic you do something like this in your code:

```
rospy.set_param('/background_b',100)
rospy.set_param('/background_r',100)
rospy.set_param('/background_g',100)
```

after that you must  call

```
rosservice call /clear
```

in terminal or in your code

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bharadwaj26](https://answers.ros.org/users/33000/bharadwaj26/) on 2018-02-27**:
can't we publish the rgb values to the color_sensor and change color ,like we publish linear and angular data to cmd_vel in turtlesim to move the turtle